# N-ary trees equals

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I did this structure to represent an N-ary tree:

```
public class MyTree {
    public int data;
    LinkedList<MyTree> children;


    public MyTree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addChild(MyTree child) {
        this.children.addFirst(child);
    }

    public boolean equals(MyTree root) { }
}
```

I also did some other methods,but they aren't the core of this method so I don't show it to you. However let's talk about the method equals:
how to check if two tree are equal in both structure and value? I mean they are equal only if:

```
  8             
 / | \20
9  10     
|
20
 |
 30
 / | \
40 50 70


  8             
 / |\20
9  10     
|
20
 |
 30
/ | \
40 50 70
```

So my idea is to do two recursion at the same time(one with this.tree and one with the tree in input),when the fuction explore the first node compare it with the first of the second tree and so on(they have to respect the same order and value!) like this:

```
public boolean equals(MyTree t) {

    boolean result = true;
    if (this == null && t == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == null || t == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getValue() != t.getValue()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getChildren().size() != t.getChildren().size() ) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.getChildren().size() == t.getChildren().size() ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
            MyTree object = t.getChildren().get(i);
            MyTree object1 = this.getChildren().get(i);
            result = object1.equals(object);
            if (result == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I don't know how to explore at the same time two tree,I did a dfs pre-order for example,but in this method you have to explore two tree at the same time. Can you give me an algorithm to explore two tree at the same time? 
My test:

```
        MyTree t1 = new MyTree(8);
        t1.addChild(new MyTree(9));
        t1.addChild(new MyTree(10));
        MyTree t2 = new MyTree(20);
        t2.addChild(new MyTree(40));
        t2.addChild(new MyTree(30));
        MyTree t3 = new MyTree(25);
        t3.addChild(new MyTree(80));
        t3.addChild(new MyTree(70));
        t3.addChild(new MyTree(95));
        t2.addChild(t3);
        t1.addChild(t2);

        MyTree t4 = new MyTree(8);
        t4.addChild(new MyTree(9));
        t4.addChild(new MyTree(10));
        MyTree t5 = new MyTree(20);
        t5.addChild(new MyTree(40));
        t5.addChild(new MyTree(30));
        MyTree t6 = new MyTree(25);
        t6.addChild(new MyTree(80));
        t6.addChild(new MyTree(70));
        t6.addChild(new MyTree(95));
        t5.addChild(t6);
        t4.addChild(t5);
        System.out.print(t1.equals(t4));
```

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a list?  Do you know how to get an element of a list at a specific index?

Comment: Yes,but for example if I use two for: one for the first tree and one for the second tree I think it takes the first element of the first tree,then go with the second for and get the first elment of the second tree.. but I think then it explore the second node of the second tree,the third node of the second tree and so on. or am I get it wrong?

Comment: You can check to see if the `children` lists are the same length; then assuming they are, you iterate over both lists with one `for` loop, using the same index for both `children` lists.  Note that you made things harder by making this a `LinkedList`, since getting an element at a specified index means stepping through the entire list multiple times.  To avoid this, you'd need to get list iterators for both lists with `t.children.iterator()` and use the iterator methods manually, since you can't use a `for` to go through two iterators in parallel.

Comment: I never used an iterator and I don't know what is it,what's the point by using an iterator there?

Comment: @ajb I did your algorithm but it seems like it only explorers the values of the roots.  I edited the question with the code.

Comment: `object1.equals(object)` returns a `boolean`, but you just throw it away.

Comment: @ajb my recursive function has to explore both nodes at the same time,until this.getValue() != t.getValue() it stops I think.. so what do you mean with "you just throw it away" ?

Comment: You don't assign the result of `equals` to anything, or use it for anything. So there's no way it knows to stop if the children are unequal, because you don't tell it to stop.

Comment: Also, it's not recommended to define `equals` with a parameter that isn't of type `Object`.  Doing this can lead to unexpected results, because it overloads the `equals` method inherited from `Object`.  I'd recommend renaming it to `treeEquals` for now, at least until you get the method right.

Comment: @ajb I think now it works only with two tree that have only one list of nodes,I edited the code in the question with some test with a tree that return false but has to return true. I don't know if you want to do a recursive call or not with your algorithm,because it dosn't work with list of lists

Comment: What is a `MyIntTree`???  This is a new type you've thrown into the code without defining it.  I have no idea what it is.  Using two tree types is just adding confusion.  Your `equals` method looks like the right algorithm, or it would be right if you were using just one tree type.  The additional information you've added is confusing and I have no idea what you're asking now.

Comment: @ajb MyIntTree is MyTree

Comment: What do you mean "MyIntTree" is "MyTree"?  Does that mean the code in your question has typos in it?  If so, please fix them.

Comment: Your test is wrong.  It looks like you tried to create one tree using `t1`, `t2` and `t3`, and a second tree using `t4`, `t5`, and `t6`.  But your code to create the second tree is still adding children to `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.  Please fix the test and retry it.  I think it will work, because your algorithm now looks correct.

Comment: @ajb Yeah my bad,sorry I am tired :| How can I test some others possibility if my code works ? or is the best case I can meet ?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: @ajb I mean do you think my code will work with all tree I use to test it? or do you reccomend me to do some other tests ?

Comment: You might want to try some tests that will return false--because some node way down in the tree is unequal, or because some node down in the tree has a different number of children.  If you wrote a _unit test_ class, I'd want to see some tests like that, plus some edge cases (empty trees).  But I think your code will work.

Comment: @ajb Uhm if I do MyTree t1 = null; MyTree t2 = null; t1.equals(t2); NullPointerException, why?

Comment: You can't call any instance method on `null`, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is going to be as follow: trees are equals only if corresponding data equals, children size are equals and each children are equals

```
public class MyTree {
public int data;
LinkedList<MyTree> children;


public MyTree(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<>();
}

public void addChild(MyTree child) {
    this.children.addFirst(child);
}

public boolean equals(MyTree root) {
    if (root == null || root.children.size() != children.size() || data != root.data) return false;

    Iterator<MyTree> myTreeIterator = children.iterator();
    Iterator<MyTree> rootTreeIterator = root.children.iterator();
    while (myTreeIterator.hasNext() && rootTreeIterator.hasNext()) {
        if (!myTreeIterator.next().equals(rootTreeIterator.next())) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

UPD: @Gene advice

```
public class MyTree {
public int data;
LinkedList<MyTree> children;


public MyTree(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<>();
}

public void addChild(MyTree child) {
    this.children.addFirst(child);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this == o || !(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) && equals((MyTree) o);
}

public boolean equals(MyTree root) {
    return !(root == null || data != root.data) && children.equals(root.children);
}
}
```

Comment: sorry, missed that

Comment: I think your iteration is unnecessary. `LinkedList`'s `equals` method already implements element-wise equality. You should override the base `equals(Object obj)` and use this fact to make your code much simpler.

Comment: I agree with you, but this code is implementation of OP contract and first of all gives explicit insight about correct recursion

Comment: Why is iterator better to use?

Comment: @HKing sorry, better than what?